# How to fix "the remote server returned an error 401 unauthorized" when using system.net.webclient?

Tags: c#, .net

i am trying to download a file from one drive-share point but it throws error like " the remote server returned an error 401 unauthorized " even i have provided my credentials too but again getting the same Error. can anyone help me to fix this issue ?

```
    WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
client1.UseDefaultCredentials = true; 
       client1.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
       client1.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Pwd"); 
       client1.DownloadFile(uri1, Afilename1);
```

Comment: It is clear that providing your credentials is not working. So you need to understand the requirements of the service and figure out what does it expect.

Comment: Use Default Credentials only.  Windows will not allow an un-encrypted Username and Password using new Credentials.  Default credentials requires the local and remote PC to be in the same group and the user account to be in both PCs.  When you use default credentials the connection between local and remote PC is encrypted and makes the connection secure.  You  can't used Default Credentials and then also use a Username and Password.  Remove the new credentials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download file from OneDrive using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271322/download-file-from-onedrive-using-microsoft-sharepoint-client)

Comment: i have downloaded microsoft sharepoint client online sdk now its showing error like "the website does not support sharepoint online credentials" when executing this line   clientContext.Load(web, website =>website.ServerRelativeUrl); 
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();